# Can an OS X application examine the launchd plist which invoked it?

Tags: macos, cocoa, plist, launchd

I'm writing an application which will potentially be invoked by more than one `launchd` job – that is, there might be two distinct LaunchAgent `.plist` files which invoke the application with different program arguments or in different conditions.  I'd like the application to be able to examine the job, or the job's `.plist`, so it can adjust its behaviour based on what it finds there.

In particular, supposing a program `foo` could be started up from both `A.plist` and `B.plist`, I'd like the program to be able to preserve different state depending on which job/plist invoked it.  If all I can do is detect the (presumed distinct) `Label` of the job, that will be enough (though more would be better).

The obvious ways to do this are using different flags in the `ProgramArguments` array in the job, or to set different values in `EnvironmentVariables`, but both of those feel fragile, both imply duplication of bits of configuration, and both require extra documentation (“copy the value of the `Label` into `EnvironmentVariables` field `FOO`...; don't ask why”).

I can see the function [`SMJobCopyDictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ServiceManagement/Reference/ServiceManagement_header_reference/Reference/reference.html).  With that, it appears that I can get access to the job's dictionary – ie, this information *is* available in principle –  but I need to know the job's label first.  Function `SMCopyAllJobDictionaries` allows me to iterate through all of the jobs, but it's not obvious how I'd find the one which invoked a particular instance of the application.

Googling `launchd read job label` or `launchd self dict` (or similar) don't come up with anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [SampleD code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SampleD/) on Apple's site. This code shows how daemon's can access calling launchd information.

Looking at the [launch.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/launchd/launchd-328/launchd/src/launch.h) header, I suspect `LAUNCH_JOBKEY_LABEL` is what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Using the ProgramArguments is, in fact, probably the best way to handle this. It will make your code more portable (e.g. making it possible to launch in Linux, for example, or under a different launch daemon) to use program arguments that configure the behavior rather than relying on the program invocation chain.

With regard to program arguments, though, I would suggest not copying the label, but rather using the specific flags that differ between the jobs. For example, you might set --checkpoint-file and --log-file in both A.plist and B.plist to files that happen to include "A" or "B" in their names. Doing this will make the application code that depends on --checkpoint-file and --log-file much clearer, though, than if it were to make arbitrary choices based on some label and will also allow you to run the command directly from the commandline and have it still work despite there not being an invoking PLIST file.

Comment: if you use `SMJobBless` to install your helper then you _can't_ use `ProgramArguments`. `SMJobBless` will completely strip out that option from the plist. I'm not sure about `EnvironmentVariables`.

Comment: I'm not much concerned with portability in this case, since I'm freely using Cocoa APIs and Darwin services (in particular FSEvents: this is a backup helper that's got a little [out of control](http://xkcd.com/974/)); it might be portable to FreeBSD and NextStep, but that's about it. For the same reason, I'm unlikely to invoke it outside of a launchd job. So yes, an --ident option (say) would work, but feels roundabout. Also, there's other information in the plist, such as `WatchPaths`, which the application could use if it could find it, and which currently has to be duplicated in options.

Answer (score 1):

**Summary**: I think the answer here is a qualified no.

Graham Miln's answer (which I've accepted) shows that this is possible in fact,
but the interface he mentions is apparently documented nowhere other than in
this sample code, and also possibly in *Mac OS X Internals: A
Systems Approach* (Amit Singh, http://osxbook.com, thanks to Mitchell J
Laurren-Ring for pointing this out).

I also asked about this on the [launchd-dev list](https://lists.macosforge.org/mailman/listinfo/launchd-dev) (see the thread starting with
[my
question](https://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/launchd-dev/2013-December/001083.html)),
and Damien Sorresso suggested that this interface was “really only so that jobs
can check in with launchd to obtain listening sockets. They were way too general
at the outset.”

Put together, I'm left with the feeling that, while the behaviour I
want seems possible, and while I think it's neater in this case than
passing more state in environment variables, the API to support such
behaviour is, if not deprecated, than at least somewhat discouraged,
and at any rate not idiomatic.